# installing aws cli on instance using pip

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using cloud formation template to install CLI on my instance during launch but when I try to run any shell script having cli commands, it shows the error of 'aws configure'. Because of permission issues, I can't attach any role or IAM user to the instance.

If there is any other to achieve the same, kindly help.

Shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
my_eth1=`aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters "Name=status,Values=available" "Name=tag:Name,Values=MyENI" "Name=subnet-id,Values=subnet-03754b9bf4816284e" --output text --query "NetworkInterfaces[0].PrivateIpAddress"`
my_eth1_id=`aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters "Name=status,Values=available" "Name=tag:Name,Values=MyENI" "Name=subnet-id,Values=subnet-03754b9bf4816284e" --output text --query "NetworkInterfaces[0].NetworkInterfaceId" | grep -o 'eni-[a-z0-9]*'`
ec2_id=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`

aws ec2 attach-network-interface --network-interface-id $my_eth1_id --instance-id $ec2_id --device-index 1
GATEWAY=`ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }'`

printf "\nGATEWAYDEV=eth0\n" >>/etc/sysconfig/network
printf "\nBOOTPROTO=dhcp\nDEVICE=eth1\nONBOOT=yes\nTYPE=Ethernet\nUSERCTL=no\n" >/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
ifup eth1

ip route add default via $GATEWAY dev eth1 tab 2

ip rule add from $my_eth1/32 tab 2 priority 600
```

Cloud formation

```
"UserData": { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                "echo 'Downloading PIP'\n",
                "curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py\n",
                "echo 'Executing PIP using Python'\n",
                "python get-pip.py --user\n",
                "echo 'Setting PIP Classpath'\n",
                "echo 'export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile\n",
                "echo 'Reloading bash_profile'\n",
                "source ~/.bash_profile\n",
                "echo 'Installing AWS CLI'\n",
                "pip install awscli --upgrade --user\n"
            ]]}}
```

Comment: Add access key, secret key token and region.

Comment: What AMI are you using, Amazon Linux AMI's have it installed by default. I would always prefer installing cli using [bundle installer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-bundle.html).

Comment: I am using red hat  ami and it's not having cli by default.  Is there a way to configure aws cli  (aws configure...)from the shell script ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post the error message taking out any sensitive information if you have